# Prolog - Predicate doesn't find all solutions when using no input variables

Tags: prolog

Here is my problem.

My facts and rules:

```
fact1(green, red, blue).
fact1(purple, white, gray).

fact2(green, orange).
fact2(purple, cyan).

fact3(green, pink).
fact3(purple, black).

foo(A,B,C,D,E) :-
   fact1(A,B,C),
   fact2(A,D),
   fact3(A,E),
   write(A),
   write(B).
```

Now if I ask SWI-Prolog `foo(A,B,C,D,E).` the output is

```
?- foo(A,B,C,D,E).
greenred
A = green, B = red, C = blue, D = orange, E = pink ;
purplewhite
A = purple, B = white, C = gray, D = cyan, E = black.
```

My goal is that the user only sees the lines

```
greenred
purplewhite
```

In order to achieve this I tried changing the definition of `foo` like so:

```
foo() :-
   fact1(A,B,C),
   fact2(A,D),
   fact3(A,E),
   write(A),
   write(B).
```

But the output of this predicate is only:

```
?- foo().
greenred
true.
```

and not what I would expect:

```
?- foo().
greenred
purplewhite
true.
```

Any help is very welcome.

Comment: What do you mean "but of course always outputs..."? You didn't tell us what your facts look like so we don't know what your expected output is. Do you actually have multiple matching facts? Can you include some minimal (dummy) data we can reproduce this with? I tried some and can't reproduce your problem. So either the problem is in the code you're not showing us, or I don't understand what you mean. How are you running this? What are you doing to try and get multiple matches?

Comment: thank you for your answer, I edited my question with some dummy code. Hope now you know what I mean.

Comment: Thanks for the update. Oh, is it the `true` output you have a problem with? Pressing Space still gives me the subsequent matches even on `foo().` but it also prints `true` after each match, which `foo(A,B,C,D,E).` doesn't do?

Comment: I tested it again and I really only get the first match with foo(), then true and then nothing.  And yes as you said I also don't get the true inbetween the lines which is also something I want if possible. Maybe it's an swi-prolog thingy? Or do you know another way how I could achieve my desired outcome?

Comment: Ok so I tested my code with the swish only editor and now I get the same output as @mercator. Interesting

Comment: Do you have some funny hidden characters? I'm afraid I don't know otherwise, nor how to get rid of the `true`. :(

Comment: I pasted the code 1:1 from SWI to swish so I don't think there is a mistake somewhere in the code. (Especially since this is dummy code and it also happens in my real code). Still, thanks for trying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding [fail/0](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=fail/0) at the end tuns this into a [failure driven loop](http://www.coli.uni-saarland.de/projects/milca/courses/coal/html/node162.html) so that once an answer is given, the predicate fails and tries the other choice points.

```
foo :-
    fact1(A,B,_),
    fact2(A,_),
    fact3(A,_),
    write(A),
    write(B),
    nl,
    fail.
```

Example run.

```
?- foo.
greenred
purplewhite
false.
```

To get Prolog to return true, (In the the background an evil voice says, "We have ways of making you give us the truth"), it needs to succeed after failing so Prolog looks for another clause named `foo`. By adding just `foo.` as a second clause Prolog can now find this clause and execute it. Since it does nothing, it succeeds and returns `true.`

```
foo.
```

Example run

```
?- foo.
greenred
purplewhite
true.
```

---

Complete source code

```
foo :-
    fact1(A,B,_),
    fact2(A,_),
    fact3(A,_),
    write(A),
    write(B),
    nl,
    fail.
foo.
```

Comment: Terminology: you meant to say "clause", not "predicate". In the 'complete' code you have 1 predicate which comprises 2 clauses (1 rule and 1 fact).

Comment: Thx so much! Very interesting that SWISH handles this diffrently compared to prolog. That's something I have to keep in mind.

Comment: @repeat Thx. Changed.